# How to get the actual X Y coordinates of pointer on element in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using onPointer events in react.js
I can get the actual XY coordinates with event.pageX and event.pageY values or client and screen.
but when I'm setting margins, paddings or moving the element to another positions, my coordinates are still from XY values of the whole screen size.
How can I reference my element?
I know that useRef() is there, but how can I reference it without subtracting paddings or margins, I want them to be relative referenced because I will use them a lot in my app.
What's your solution?

```js
const App = () => {
  const [coordinates, setCoordinates] = useState([]);

  return <div
    style={{margin: "30px"}}
    onPointerDown=
      {(event) => setCoordinates([...coordinates, `{event.clientX} {event.clientY}`]}
    id="elementiwanttoref">{coordinates.map((cord) => <span>{cord}</span>)}</div>
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue via `nativeEvent` property

Comment: Could you please share some code on how you made it work?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
const App = () => {
    const inputRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
      console.log(inputRef.current.offsetLeft);
      console.log(inputRef.current.offsetTop);
    }, []);

    <Component ref={inputRef} />
}
```

Comment: i'll get undefined

Comment: i want to pointer coordinates, based on the height and widths of component that i'm referencing, not the actual page

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you are looking for a coordinates relatively to element. With [`offsetX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetX) and [`offsetY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/offsetY) properties we can get this, but it will be relatively to event listener's target element(we cannot re-calculate dynamically for some random another element).